# How to parse a JSON response which does not have a name for its list

Tags: java, json

I have following JSON response, that need to be parsed to a class. As it does not have any root I do not know how to parse it.

```
 [{
    "Id":18,
    "Name":"Albume One",
    "SubTitle":null,
    "Description":null,
    "Date":"3/7/2014 8:00 PM",
    "City":null,
    "State":null,
    "Production":13
    },
    {"Id":200,
```

I use the following code but do not know how to iterate through each field of set of result:

```
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONArray msg = (JSONArray)parser.parse(buff.readLine());
        for(int i=0;i<msg.size();i++)
        {
            System.err.println(msg.get(0).toString());

        }



 {"Id":18,"Name":"Albume One","SubTitle":null,"Description":null,"Date":"3/7/2014 8:00 PM","City":null,"State":null,"Production":13}
 {"Id":200, .....
```

Is there any library to auto-parse the JSON rather than using loops, such as Jackson library for XMLs.

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax!!!  What you have is a array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following

```
JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();

  System.out.println("=======decode=======");

  String s="[0,{\"1\":{\"2\":{\"3\":{\"4\":[5,{\"6\":7}]}}}}]";
  Object obj=parser.parse(s);
  JSONArray array=(JSONArray)obj;
  System.out.println("======the 2nd element of array======");
  System.out.println(array.get(1));
  System.out.println();

  JSONObject obj2=(JSONObject)array.get(1);
  System.out.println("======field \"1\"==========");
  System.out.println(obj2.get("1"));    


  s="{}";
  obj=parser.parse(s);
  System.out.println(obj);

  s="[5,]";
  obj=parser.parse(s);
  System.out.println(obj);

  s="[5,,2]";
  obj=parser.parse(s);
  System.out.println(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to ve a root to it. Just consider it as an array of JSON and parse it . you will get array of JSON Objects. Iterate through it and get the value your want...

Try something like:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONArray msg = (JSONArray)parser.parse(buff.readLine());
    for(int i=0;i<msg.length();i++)
    {
          JSONObject jsonobj=   msg.getJSONObject(i);
      sysout(jsonobj.get("KEY"));

    }
```

Comment: Except that it's not Strings in the array, it's JSON objects (Maps).

Comment: the result of parse should be casted to JSONArray, not sure how to retrieve iterator.next as well.

Comment: I VE UPDATED MY ANSWER.. TRY IT

Answer (score -1):

You can use [gson api](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for this purpose. Here is the sample code :

```
public class Bean {
        private int Id;
        private String Name;
        private String SubTitle;
        private String Description;
        private String Date;
        private String City;
        private String State;
        private int Production;
        public int getId() {
            return Id;
        }
        public void setId(int id) {
            Id = id;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return Name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            Name = name;
        }
        public String getSubTitle() {
            return SubTitle;
        }
        public void setSubTitle(String subTitle) {
            SubTitle = subTitle;
        }
        public String getDescription() {
            return Description;
        }
        public void setDescription(String description) {
            Description = description;
        }
        public String getDate() {
            return Date;
        }
        public void setDate(String date) {
            Date = date;
        }
        public String getCity() {
            return City;
        }
        public void setCity(String city) {
            City = city;
        }
        public String getState() {
            return State;
        }
        public void setState(String state) {
            State = state;
        }
        public int getProduction() {
            return Production;
        }
        public void setProduction(int production) {
            Production = production;
        }



    }
```

for testing :

```
@Test
    private void test() {

        Gson g = new Gson();
        String jsonString = "[{ \"Id\":18, \"Name\":\"Albume One\", \"SubTitle\":null, \"Description\":null, \"Date\":\"3/7/2014 8:00 PM\", \"City\":null, \"State\":null, \"Production\":13 }]";
        Type token = new TypeToken<List<Bean>>(){}.getType();
        List<Bean> list = g.fromJson(jsonString, token);
        for (Bean bean : list) {
            System.out.println(bean.getName());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what toolkit you use ...

```
JSONArray array = parser.parse(jsonString);
for (JSONObject object : array) {
    int id = object.getInt("Id");
    String name = object.getString("Name");
    ....
}
```